# How to use CUDA Thrust execution policy to override Thrust's low-level device memory allocator

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, malloc, thrust

I want to override the low-level CUDA device memory allocator (implemented as thrust::system::cuda::detail::malloc()) so that it uses a custom allocator instead of call directly to cudaMalloc() when invoked on a host (CPU) thread.

Is this possible?  If so, is it possible to use the Thrust "execution policy" mechanism to do it?  I have tried a model like this:

```
struct eptCGA : thrust::system::cuda::detail::execution_policy<eptCGA>
{
};

/// overload the Thrust malloc() template function implementation
template<typename eptCGA> __host__ __device__ void* malloc( eptCGA, size_t n )
{
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
    return MyMalloc( n );   /* (called from a host thread) */
#else
    return NULL;            /* (called from a device GPU thread) */
#endif
}


/* called as follows, for example */
eptCGA epCGA;
thrust::remove_if( epCGA, ... );
```

This works.  But there are other components of Thrust that call down to the low-level malloc implementation, seemingly without using the "execution policy" mechanism.  For example,

```
    thrust::device_vector<UINT64> MyDeviceVector( ... );
```

does not expose an overload with an "execution policy" parameter.  Instead, malloc() gets invoked at the bottom of 15 nested function calls, using an execution policy that is seemingly hardwired into one of the Thrust functions somewhere in the middle of that call stack.

Can someone please clarify how the approach I am taking is incorrect, and explain what a workable implementation should be doing?

Comment: @RobertCrovella:  Thanks, but the code example you're referring to is over four years old, predates Thrust's support for execution policies, and isn't really on point since it's basically about overriding Thrust's temporary-buffer allocator, not its low-level memory allocator.

Comment: I don't understand this question - execution policy and the memory allocator are orthogonal concepts. You shouldn't ever try overloading *anything* in thrust::system. If you want to use a custom allocator, implement your own model of thrust::allocator. That is what it is for. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @talonmies:  I apologize if the question isn't clear.  In order to use a GPU-memory allocator implementation that replaces cudaMalloc, I want to override the Thrust implementation at the point where it calls cudaMalloc.  That particular Thrust implementation supports the execution-policy mechanism, which makes for an easy-to-implement template overload.  The problem with this is that different code paths internal to Thrust do not all seem to pass the execution-policy parameter all the way through.  In particular, Thrust's temporary-buffer allocator does, but device_vector doesn't.

Comment: `device_vector` uses its allocator for memory allocation. If you want to customize the way `device_vector` allocates memory, give it a custom memory allocator.

Comment: @JaredHoberock:  Thank you for your comment.  I take it to mean that, to ensure that Thrust always uses the custom cudaMalloc replacement, I need to override the Thrust implementation wherever it might need to call through cudaMalloc (e.g., device_vector, the temporary-buffer allocator, and perhaps elsewhere).  That's unfortunate because the execution-policy mechanism would provide a concise solution to the problem if only Thrust itself were implemented to use it where it currently doesn't (like in device_vector).

Comment: @B.Picsou: That's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something that worked for me. You can create both a custom execution policy and allocator which use your custom malloc all in one go:

```
#include <thrust/system/cuda/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/system/cuda/memory.h>
#include <thrust/system/cuda/vector.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>

// create a custom execution policy by deriving from the existing cuda::execution_policy
struct my_policy : thrust::cuda::execution_policy<my_policy> {};

// provide an overload of malloc() for my_policy
__host__ __device__ void* malloc(my_policy, size_t n )
{
  printf("hello, world from my special malloc!\n");

  return thrust::raw_pointer_cast(thrust::cuda::malloc(n));
}

// create a custom allocator which will use our malloc
// we can inherit from cuda::allocator to reuse its existing functionality
template<class T>
struct my_allocator : thrust::cuda::allocator<T>
{
  using super_t = thrust::cuda::allocator<T>;
  using pointer = typename super_t::pointer;

  pointer allocate(size_t n)
  {
    T* raw_ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(malloc(my_policy{}, sizeof(T) * n));

    // wrap the raw pointer in the special pointer wrapper for cuda pointers
    return pointer(raw_ptr);
  }
};

template<class T>
using my_vector = thrust::cuda::vector<T, my_allocator<T>>;

int main()
{
  my_vector<int> vec(10, 13);
  vec.push_back(7);

  assert(thrust::count(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 13) == 10);

  // because we're superstitious
  my_policy policy;
  auto new_end = thrust::remove(policy, vec.begin(), vec.end(), 13);
  vec.erase(new_end, vec.end());
  assert(vec.size() == 1);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the output on my system:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -I. test.cu -run
hello, world from my special malloc!
hello, world from my special malloc!
hello, world from my special malloc!
hello, world from my special malloc!
```

You could get even fancier and use the `thrust::pointer<T,Tag>` wrapper to incorporate `my_policy` into a custom `pointer` type. This would have the effect of tagging `my_vector`'s iterators with `my_policy` instead of the CUDA execution policy. That way, you wouldn't have to provide an explicit execution policy with each algorithm invocation (as the example does with the invocation of `thrust::remove`). Instead, Thrust would know to use your custom execution policy just by looking at the types of `my_vector`'s iterator.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sure I can use your model code to build a workable solution in my application, so I am marking your response as an SO "answer".  Nevertheless, this code fails to address some fundamental problems with Thrust's low-level memory-allocation implementation.  I'm not knocking Thrust, which I have found to be of great value in efficiently handling common GPU-based tasks, but the particular problem of providing Thrust with a customized memory allocator is long-standing and really ought to be handled better...

Comment: As things stand now, despite our magic knowledge of how Thrust is implemented and despite two separate overrides, there's still no guarantee that something elsewhere in Thrust won't ever call through to cudaMalloc in yet another way.  For example, there are explicit calls to cudaMalloc in Thrust's CUB code -- how do you know if-or-when they'll ever execute? Furthermore, your model code overrides malloc, not system::detail::malloc, which introduces another way for some component of Thrust to bypass the custom low-level cudaMalloc replacement (i.e., by calling system::detail::malloc directly)...

Comment: Your model code also hard-wires a reference to the derived memory allocator in order to get Thrust to use it for application-level memory allocations (e.g., instantiating a device_vector).  If Thrust supported overriding memory-allocation functionality at an appropriately low level (i.e., where cudaMalloc gets called) and if Thrust consistently used its own low-level implementation, these problems would go away, the execution-policy mechanism would provide compile-time control... and maybe people would quit asking how to inject a device-memory allocator into Thrust!

Comment: 7 years later, I have the same question as @B.Picsou. Is there any update? I couldn't find any doc online